# Can Oracle Reports 10g create a PDF with usable text fields?

Tags: oracle10g, pdf-generation, acrobat, oraclereports

I have an Oracle Reports 10g report, that pulls data from the database and saves the result as a PDF file on the user's PC.  The users are requesting that the resultant PDF have a couple of text fields, so they can open the the PDF in Adobe Acrobat and type in some data (small amounts, like dates and filenames; not entire paragraphs or anything) and then save the PDF with the data.

Is this even possible?  And if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, the users have  Adobe Acorbat  Professional to type and save them.
We have done some files:
File
Generate to File
PDF
We open the file from Adobe Acorbat  Professional application  to edit and save.
If you have more question for us please let us know.

Comment: We are already creating the PDF, that's not the issue.  We need the PDF to have fields in it.  Do you have any idea how to do that?  I haven't been able to find a way in Reports Builder  to create a PDF text field.

Comment: Please view our way: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-FWD9OcsOhJI/TVv_0kuCviI/AAAAAAAAAKQ/FDS4YjL5y1U/s1600/PDFout0.bmp